# Why my 2d graphic application run faster on Inegrated graphics card?

Tags: opengl, gpu, opentk

I am working on a 2D graphic application with OpenGL(like QGIS). Recently when I was testing some benchmarks, there was a weird performance difference between my 2 Graphic Cards. So I made a simple test and draw just 1 million squares using VBO. So there are 4m vertices each 20 bytes, So my total VBO size is 80 MB. And I draw whole things with just one DrawElements call. When I measured render time in my laptop which has 2 Graphic Cards it runs about 43 ms on Geforce and about 1 ms on Integrated Intel card. But I expected to be faster on Geforce. Why is it so? Should I disable some 
Opengl options?

My System specification is:
ASUS N53m With Integrated Graphics Card and Geforce GT 610m

**EDIT**:
I also tested on another system with AMD Radeon HD 5450, it was about 44 ms again. I also used single precision instead and it reduced to 30 ms. But still integrated GPU is more faster!
It is definitely not measuring issue, because I can see the lag when zoom in/out.

Comment: How are you measuring your performance?

Comment: I used Stopwatch before draw start and after glFinish measured the difference

Comment: Maybe the integrated card discard evething.

Comment: I don't think so, because when zoom in/out occurs objects are still there. I tried to discard vbo buffer data, but everything cleared and nothing showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run *time* behavior of different OpenGL implementations vastly differs as I found out in my experiments regarding low-latency rendering techniques for VR. In general the only truly reliable timing interval to measure, that gives consistent results is inter-frame time between the very same step in your drawing. I.e. measure the time from buffer swap to buffer swap (if you want to measure raw drawing performance, disable V-Sync), or between the same `glClear` calls.

Everything else is only consistent within a certain implementation, but not between vendors (at the time of testing this I had no AMD GPU around, so I lack data on this). A few notable corner cases I discovered:

- SwapBuffers

  - NVidia: returns only after the swap buffer has been presented. That means: Either waits for V-Sync or returns only after the buffers have been swapped
  - Intel/Linux/X11: always returns immediately. V-Sync affects the next OpenGL call that'd effects pixels in the not-yet-presented buffer *and* that does not fit into the command queue. Hence "clearing" the viewport with a large quad, skybox or using the depth-ping-pong method (found only in very old applications) gives very inconsistent frame intervals. glClear will reliably block until V-Sync after swap
- glFinish

  - NVidia: actually finishes the rendering, as expected
  - Intel/Linux/X11: drawing to back buffer, acts like a No-Op, drawing to front buffer acts like a finish followed by a copy from an auxiliary back to front buffer (weird); essentially means you can't make the drawing process "visible".

I yet have to test what the Intel driver does if bypassing X11 (using KMS). Note that the OpenGL specification leaves it up to the implementation how and when it does certain things, as long as the outcome is consistent and conforms to the specification. And all the observed behavior is perfectly conformant.

Comment: You are correct, this is because of SwapBuffers different behaviors. When I zoom in with Mouse Wheel, multiple draw calls happen sequentially (about 4 calls with little scroll) Intel discards current swapping and starts new swap before finishes the previous one but NVidia not. This causes lag while I am zooming.